# Simulating focus in enzyme is not changing document.activeElement

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I mount the component, simulate focus on a button, and then check the result of `document.activeElement`, which is still `<body>`. What am I missing here?

```
const app = mount(<Component />);

app.find("button").simulate('focus');

const focusedElement = document.activeElement; // result: <body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2173#issuecomment-505551552

`simulate` is not simulation in many senses:

1. event does not bubble up
2. it does nothing with `document.activeElement`
3. simulating `click` does not trigger either `mouseDown`, `blur` or `focus`

You cannot test that with jest/enzyme.
I guess you can test that with Selenium or something similar.